# Openshift: SSH key denied, even though they match

Tags: ssh, encryption, openshift-online-2

I am attempting to use the *OpenShift RHC* tool on a Windows machine to ssh into one of my applications. The public key associated with my OpenShift account matches my `.\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` and I've even regenerated the public key from the private key file to verify. But I keep getting disconnected with the error `"no supported authentication methods available"` followed by he auth methods. Publickey is listed, so I don't understand why this is so difficult. Does anyone know what I may have overlooked?

The raw data log Putty generates can be found here:  http://pastebin.com/q13v6aWJ

Comment: Please edit your question and include verbose ssh logs from both the client and the server.

Comment: I have added a link to thePuTTY client log, not sure how I would get the server logs without having ssh access though

Comment: "Server refused our key" ... how did you add the key to putty?

Comment: I added it through pageant. Is that the wrong way?

Comment: Same error here... :(